# Problem function call before re render in vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, set

I have a problem, when I add an element in my bdd and my view client (with `$set`), a function is called. But I have error for accessing data, with the `console.log`, I see the new data is added but the data inside the object is not.

This is my error:

> vue.esm.js?efeb:610 [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined"

```js
for (var i = 0; i < this.assignments.length; i++) {
   var date1 = new Date(date);
   var date2 = new Date(this.assignments[i].start);

   if (user === this.assignments[i].User.id) {
```

Comment: How does your initial data look like?

Comment: `for (var i in this.assignments) {` may work better

Comment: no it's the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is saying that you are accessing an undefined value in this case the `User` of `this.assignments[i].User` is undefined.

Edit : To be sure check every thing

```js
if (this.assignments && this.assignments[i] && this.assignments[i].User && user === this.assignments[i].User.id)
```

Comment: I have already try this, doesnt work i have always the same error..

Comment: and maybe `this.assignments[i]` depending on how the OP is filling the array.

Comment: this is undefined because my new data is not load before call, i need to call my function with this data for change the color..

Answer (score 0):

Well.. 
If I see problem like this, I am always trying to put `debugger` right after console.log in order to stop executing script. Don't always trust console.logs someone somewhen said.

Probably with that debugger, console.log will show something different, and that's because it's holding reference, so it's filled later. (you will be able to see that in the console)

Anyway...
What You can try to do for sure is 
`await this.$nextTick()` - waiting for next render, then continue 
Put it right before your not working code.

If not you can try forbidden technique - to wrap your code in

```
setTimeout(()=>{
 ...your code which needs to wait for render
},0)
```